# Why is regex not working when I'm trying to replace a @mention?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

My current code is like this:

```
var regex = '@([a-z0-9_]+)';
replacedText = replacedText.replace(regex, '<a href="http://blah.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

However, when I type a sentence like 'hello this is @test!' it doesn't change anything and it still shows in plain text.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would also add `A-Z` in order to support uppercase letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you've created `regex` as a string. When you pass a string the `replace` method, it doesn't treat it like a regular expression; it looks for a literal occurrence of that string to replace.

Use a regular expression literal instead:

```
var regex = /@([a-z0-9_]+)/;
replacedText = replacedText.replace(regex, '<a href="http://blah.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

Or invoke the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
var regex = new RegExp('@([a-z0-9_]+)');
replacedText = replacedText.replace(regex, '<a href="http://blah.com/$1">$1</a>');
```

Here's a working [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/eL6Az/).

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work for me, unfortunately. The text isn't replaced.

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 I've included a working demonstration. See my updated answer.